# Using AdMob from within a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I've begun working on a new application and I decided to start this one off using `Fragment`s via the v13 Support package so I can build one app that does both phone & tablet designs.

I have my AdMob ads working from within a Fragment if I do the creation of them from within the XML file, however, if I try to create them via code I'm running into issues.

```
public class Fragment_Admob extends Fragment implements AdListener 
{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Fragment_Admob";

    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.admob_view, container, false);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "My_AdMob_Code");

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Eclipse tells me:

> The constructor AdView(Fragment_Admob, AdSize, String) is undefined

so I was like ok that makes sense as AdView expects an Activity and not a Fragment.  So I tried making the class extend FragmentActivity instead of Fragment and that resolved that particular issue.  However now I have fragment expansion issues at runtime which I've worked through before but I am unable to resolve here because I really don't think I'm supposed to use FragmentActivity in a non-activity set of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized I was going about it all wrong trying to put an ad inside of a Fragment.  I instead made my class extend FragmentActivity and then made my layout a RelativeLayout and injected a new RelativeLayout at the bottom with the correct gravity to make it stick.  The Fragments then reside inside of the RelativeLayout and get sized accordingly.

```
public class MyClass extends FragmentActivity implements AdListener 
{
    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "MY_ID");
    // Set the AdListener.
    adView.setAdListener(this);
    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size until the ad is loaded.
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_layout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adsParams =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    adsParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(adView,adsParams);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```